# Docker - Combining MySQL and OpenJDK images into one

Tags: java, mysql, docker, mybatis

My use case involves a MySQL DB and [Mybatis Migrations](https://mybatis.org/migrations/) to run scripts on the DB. Mybatis requires Java to be able to function. So, I need a JRE in the MySQL image. I'm currently searching for ways to use multiple images (MySQL and OpenJDK in this case) but not getting a concrete solution.

I have come across multi-stage builds, but this doesn't seem to fit my use case. What I believe I need is only the java executables to be present in my DB image.

The MySQL part of my image is working. All I need the java executable in that container and I'll be golden. How can I go about this ?
Thanks!

Comment: Short answer: don't do that. Use multiple containers. You can build your migration image against a base openjdk image and connect the container you start from it to MySQL.

Comment: I was afraid it might come down to that :( But yeah will give it a try. Still curious tho, ignoring any "standard practices" or extra effort is it possible to do what I mentioned in the question ?

Comment: Why afraid ? It's much easier to use docker how it is intended to: separating every part you run in its own micro service. Take whatever tutorial to run e.g. a spingboot application with docker-compose and you will have all the basics.

Comment: Ah no not afraid to try. Just that now I gotta refactor my stuff. I didn't realize the java problem until the end so gotta redo most of things that's why :) Was hoping something like this would be possible.

Comment: I think this is a very reasonable question and haven't seen a real answer/solution except that the 'proper' approach is to use multiple containers. Image we have an application that for some reason uses both Java and python, is there a straightforward, not over-killing, solution in docker for that kind of situation?